# SQL: How to find exact matches of words within a text

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, match, multiple-tables

Please bear with me, I'm new to Access and SQL.

What I'm trying to do is to write a SQL query to filter through two tables - one contains words that are split into two columns and the other contains text. Essentially, what I want is a new table that gives me all of the exact matches of the two columns of words with the column of text.

Here's an analogous database to simulate what I want as a result:

```
Table A:
FirstName:               LastName:
John                     Doe
Jane                     Doe
Josh                     Smith
James                    Jones
David                    Johnson

Table B:
FullName:
Jake Davidson
Mike Peters
Jason James
John Michael Smith

Query Result:
FirstName:   LastName:      FullName:
John         Doe            John Michael Smith
Josh         Smith          John Michael Smith
James        Jones          Jason James
```

(notice that the David - Davidson match didn't come up. i.e. I'd like exact matches only)

So help me fill in the blanks:

```
SELECT TableA.FirstName,TableA.LastName, TableB.FullName
FROM TableA,TableB
WHERE TableB.FullName LIKE (has an exact match with TableA.FirstName--not sure what to put )
UNION
SELECT TableA.FirstName,TableA.LastName, TableB.FullName
FROM TableA,TableB
WHERE TableB.FullName LIKE (has an exact match with TableA.LastName--not sure what to put)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be dependant on what you want it to do with FullNames with more than two names, like  "John Jacob Smith", but, assuming you want it to ignore the middle word[s],
then try

```
 Select firstname, lastname, fullname 
 from tableA a 
   Join tableb f 
      On f.firstname = Mid(a.fullname, 1, InStr(a.fullname, " ")-1) 
   Join tableb l 
      On l.lastname = Mid(a.fullname, InStrRev(a.FullNamee, " ")+1)
```

Comment: It's not actually names that I'm searching through, so the middle word is important. It's just an analogous database to simplify the concept. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that compares each `FullName` to both `Firstname` and `LastName`:

```
select a.Firstname, a.LastName, b.FullName
from tableA as a inner join
     tableB as b
     on instr(' '&b.FullName&' ', ' '&a.FirstName&' ') > 0 and
        instr(' '&b.FullName&' ', ' '&a.Lastname&' ') > 0
```

It assume that the delimiter for names is a space (as in your example).  The comparison attaches a space onto the beginning and end of `FullName` and then looks for a space-padded first name and last name.

Comment: Adding the space before and after the full name is pretty ingenious, and will definitely solve my problem. However, I'm still getting an error message that says there is a syntax error in the FROM clause. What do the lowercase a and b mean? do I have to change them to TableA and TableB when I write this out?

Comment: @Cabral . . . Those are aliases for the table, which make queries much easier to read.  In Access, I think the keyword `as` is needed before the alias (this is not needed in other databases).

Comment: Here's what I have now - SELECT Firstname,LastName, FullName FROM TableA AS A, TableB AS B ON instr(' '& B.FullName&' ', ' '& A.FirstName&' ') > 0 and instr(' '& B.FullName&' ', ' '& A.Lastname&' ') > 0; I'm still getting an error message for a syntax error. Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems to highlight the 'join' part of the statement and says that there is a syntax error in the 'FROM' clause. I'm in Access 2007 if that makes a difference...